# Angular debug function to show use of injected items

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a utility function to list dependencies between angular modules...

```
function getModules(name){
    var module = angular.module(name), out = {};
    module._invokeQueue.forEach(function(value){
        value[2][0] && console.log(module.name, value[1] + ": " + value[2][0]);
    })
    out[name] = module.requires.length ? _.map(module.requires, getModules) : [];
    return out;
}
```

This gives me a list of all the registered injectables, and what module they were registered by, and also a list of the dependencies between modules, which is all working fine.

### How can I also list use of each injectable

If I have a service called `user` which was created in `myApp` module, I want to know where it is being injected. I would be happy with detecting only when injected in function declaration, and not cases where `$injector` service might have been called directly.

I can't even figure out the right terms to search for this in google.

---

**clarification:**

I want to get a list of services/controllers etc... that load another service/constant etc...

... so if I have a service `user`, I want to get a list of all the other services/controllers that use it...

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('SuperCtrl', function(user){ /* this one has used user */ });

debug_helper.getUsesOf('user');
// I want this to return ['SuperCtrl']
```

Comment: afaik you can only get it from a element that has ng-scope on it, i.e. ```angular.element(document.querySelector('.ng-scope')).injector().get('user')```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the caller? [Angular #injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)

**Methods**

```
get(name, [caller]);
Return an instance of the service.
```

or if service exists

```
has(name);
Allows the user to query if the particular service exists.
```

Comment: please see my clarification

Comment: Does this means that if you have a list of controllers, then you can retrieve a list of services it uses using a register service? ie. register modules controllers, each controller has a list of services (iterator), map it ( list of services to controllers ).